# No authorization information present on Microsoft Graph API request

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

[image]

I try to call this API -> https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/chats
I'm also passed Authorization Bearer token in header but i got below error

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Forbidden",
        "message": "No authorization information present on the request.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2023-01-12T09:37:45",
            "request-id": "1975336f-42b0-49a1-8110-a1092f07c130",
            "client-request-id": "1975336f-42b0-49a1-8110-a1092f07c130"
        }
    }
}
```

I have use this scopes to generate token

```
user.read Mail.Send Mail.Read Mail.ReadBasic Mail.ReadWrite GroupMember.Read.All Group.Read.All Directory.Read.All Group.ReadWrite.All Directory.ReadWrite.All Chat.ReadBasic Chat.Read Chat.ReadWrite openid profile offline_access
```

I have use this endpoint https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token for acquire token

By using generated token I'm able to send mail , receive mail and etc but not able to call /chats api and other microsoft teams api

What should i do to get successful response from https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/chats API.

I got this scope in token authorized response
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6Gfh.png)

Comment: How did you acquire the token? What scopes did you use?

Comment: user.read Mail.Send Mail.Read Mail.ReadBasic Mail.ReadWrite GroupMember.Read.All Group.Read.All Directory.Read.All Group.ReadWrite.All Directory.ReadWrite.All Chat.ReadBasic Chat.Read Chat.ReadWrite openid profile offline_access

Comment: I have use this scopes because I need describe whole permissions , anything missed there for integrate microsoft teams graph api's ?

Comment: Could you include which Grant Flow you are using to generate the token?

Comment: I get token by using token API , mail send , mail receive all api's work fine but only got issue in teams api's

Comment: You mentioned that you are able to send mail , receive mail via the access token you generated, so I assume you already created the correct access token, but you can still trying to decode the token you used in https://jwt.io     to check if the `scp` claim contained `Chat.ReadBasic Chat.Read Chat.ReadWrite` in the list. If yes, then the token should be right. If not, follow Rukmmini's answer to generate your code again. If the token is correct, pls make sure if your account is assigned the teams license correctly, if your account didn't have teams license, you may also get 403 errror.

Comment: here's a link for troubleshooting 403： https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/resolve-auth-errors#steps-to-resolve-common-errors

Comment: @TinyWang what do you mean team license ? can you please explain me ? what should i do to run all teams API ?

Comment: assume you created a new account in your tenant, account id is `userA@xx.onmicrosoft.com`, then can you use this account to sign in the Teams client? obviously you can't. This is a work/school account, you have to have a license to your account. The license can be, like [M365 license](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compare-microsoft-365-enterprise-plans).

Comment: When I try to add scope Chat.ReadWrite in couple of scope container variable 
Like this :-`user.read Mail.Send Mail.Read Mail.ReadBasic Mail.ReadWrite Chat.ReadWrite openid profile offline_access`

 It's not  showing in token response scope variable values , so exactly what's happend ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results like below:***

I created an **Azure AD Application** and added API permission:

[image]

I generated the access token using **Authorization Code Flow**.

Generated Access token using below parameters:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?

&client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=RedirectURI
&response_mode=query
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/Chat.ReadWrite
&state=12345
```

[image]

I generated the access token by using below parameters:

```json
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/Chat.ReadWrite
grant_type:authorization_code
redirect_uri:RedirectUri
code:code
```

[image]

To get the chat, I used the below query:

```json
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/chats
```

[image]

***If still the issue persists***, check if the licenses are assigned to the user.

**Reference:**

[Get chat - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chat-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)