# Why I am getting "No authorization information present on the request." from Graph explorer even though all required permission are given?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, graph-explorer

I am getting below error while calling simple graph api from explorer.

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/chats/FEAIj3m6uofGd-3BQ/messages

Even though i have given all the permissions highlighted by Graph Explorer

[image]

I have taken reference of [No authorization information present on Microsoft Graph API request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75094328/no-authorization-information-present-on-microsoft-graph-api-request)

Comment: What kind of user did you sign in as? Does this user have access to Teams?

Comment: Hi @juunas, Yes This user has got access to teams.

Comment: Please make sure you have provided below permissions `Chat.ReadBasic`, `Chat.Read`, `Chat.ReadWrite`. Navigate to 'Modify permissions' tab as mentioned in the error message and grant those required permissions.

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be due there is no admin grant for the above permissions as seen below:

[image]

You can also decode your token in https://jwt.ms/ and check in scopes whether the required permissions are available.

Hope this helps.